# How do you manually set the category and status of a channel form?

Tags: channel, channel-form

Right now I have this simple test form:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="data" category="6" status="Closed" return="contact/thanks" }
   <input name="title" type="text">

   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
{/exp:channel:form}
```

The data is submitted but it doesn't set the status or the category. Maybe I am misunderstanding the documentation on how this should work.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that the behavior you're experiencing is an accepted bug, at least for the status. See the [bug tracker](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19788).

There doesn't appear to be a fix posted, but you could potentially create the status and category fields as hidden inputs, if security isn't a big concern.

Comment: Bummer. Still not fixed as of 2.10.1.

Comment: And ... updating an old site, been bitten by categories not remaining set when not in hidden form field